# Codeigniter file upload code not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

Controller Code:

```
if(isset($_FILES['imageupload']) && $_FILES['imageupload']['size'] > 0){
    echo 'inside if';
    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('imageupload'))
    {
    echo 'inside if';
    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
    }
    else
    {
    echo 'inside else';
    $upload_data = $this->upload->data(); 
    $file_name[] = $upload_data['file_name'];
    } 
}
```

View Code:

```
<input type="file" class="default" id="imageupload" name="imageupload">
```

ERROR: Call to a member function do_upload() on a non-object

Hoow can I resolve this error please help me.

Comment: what's the contents of your __construct function?

Comment: no __construct in controller

Comment: Can you please share you `HTML` code also? I guess something is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you load the library upload on your controller? I guess the problem of your code is lacking of this code `$this->load->library('upload', $config);` try to check this documentation hope it will help you. https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that the `upload` library is not loaded. You need to load the upload library somewhere and in the constructor of the controller is one possible choice. Add the following to the controller code.

```
function __construct()
{
  parent::__construct();
  $this->load->library('upload');
}
```

The other place to load this library is in **application/config/autoload.php** using the `$autoload['libraries']` item.

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('upload');
```

Other libraries can be loaded at the same time. See the comments in autoload.php for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Add upload library before you could call do_upload with config

```
$config['upload_path'] = '/path/';
$config['allowed_types'] = '*';
$config['file_name'] = 'file_name';
$config['overwrite'] = TRUE|FALSE;

$this->load->library('upload', $config);
```